# Reload TableView from different ViewController using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reload

I'm not sure about how to achieve this and hence i'm asking this question.

I have 2 ViewController(VC) named `abVC` and `xyVC`. 
`abVC` contains only `TableView` and `xyVC` contains only a button.

When i tap a button on `xyVC`, it should reload tableview inside `abVC` without moving to that `abVC`.

Is it possible ? If yes.. then please help me,How to do that?

Comment: you can use NSNotifications

Comment: add NSNotidfication Observer in abVC. post notification from xyVC when button is pressed.

Comment: Another approach could be using a delegate. But that depends on the architecture of the app.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with both block and NSNotification.

**With block you can implement it as follows:**

make a property as follows in xyzVC.h:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)void(^callBack)();
```

Synthesize this property in xyzVC.m

```
@synthesize callBack
```

Call this block in Buttons click event

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(UIButton *)sender {

if (callBack)
    {
        callBack();
    }

}
```

Implement it in abcVC where you want call back:

```
[abVC setCallBack:^{
        //reload your tableview here
    }];
```

**With NSNotification you can implement it as follows:**

Register for receiving notification in abcVC.m

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTableView) name:@"ReloadTable" object:nil];

- (void)reloadTableView{
  // Reload your tableview here
}
```

Now post the notification from xyzVC

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(UIButton *)sender {

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTable" object:nil];

}
```

**Note:** If you are using NSNotification then don't forget to remove it when your view controller is dismissed

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this line in your button action method

   `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTable" object:nil];`
2. Add this code where you have implemented table, so in `abVC`:

   1. inside `viewDidLoad`:

   `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTableViewData) name:@"ReloadTable" object:nil];`

   2. Add following method

   `- (void)reloadTableViewData{`
      `[self.myTableView reloadData];`
   `}`

   3. Implement `dealloc` method (to prevent crash)

   `- (void)dealloc{`
      `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ReloadTable" object:nil];`
   `}`